# Unable to get the value from realm db schema

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm creating a visitor management app using react-native and realm as DB.
For adding the Visitor I'm using PopUpDialog with various text fields. 
One is Headercomponent which has the title and "+" for showing the popup.

```
export const TodoSchema = {
    name: TODO_SCHEMA,
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int',    // primary key
        name: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        age: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        reason: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        address: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        visitorid: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        visitingperson: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        number: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
        done: { type: 'bool', default: false }
    }
};
export const TodoListSchema = {
    name: TODOLIST_SCHEMA,
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int',    // primary key
        name: 'string',
        creationDate: 'date',
        exitDate: 'date',
        todos: { type: 'list', objectType: TODO_SCHEMA }
    }
};
```

Now in the main component, I'm trying to get the value of creationDate and it is coming up as undefined aNY SUGGESTIONS would be good

Code for MainComponent.js

```
Imports required for components

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { updateTodoList, deleteTodoList, queryAllTodoLists } from '../databases/allSchemas';
import realm from '../databases/allSchemas';
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';

import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent';
import PopupDialogComponent from './PopupDialogComponent';

let FlatListItem = props => {
    const { itemIndex, id, name, creationDate, exitDate, popupDialogComponent, onPressItem } = props;
```

Here i'm trying to get the objects from the db creationdate,name,id is is retured as undefined